# What is being said in this audio clip ( 4 seconds )?

Tags: translation, listening

Hopefully this is the last question of this kind I post on this forum for long time. I'm sorry for bothering with this probably annoying format, I'm trying to translate a movie from subtitles that are terribly made and your help was essential for this.

The audio is [this](https://instaud.io/3iUP) one.

The translation I have is this:

- Report the shadow's position ( said during a tailing )
- Do you want your head covered? ( A man is pointing a gun to the head of the person this sentence is addressed to )
- You're too much! ( The mom of a girl finds out that she quarreled with her uncle and she doesn't seem happy of this )

Thanks for all your support. Much love from me!

Comment: Personally I'm not annoyed and I hope you post more questions and answers and enjoy our site. Since you have a rough translation may be you also have a rough idea of what is being said in the clip? If that's correct then please consider posting a transcript (doesn't have to be accurate, may be even mix Korean and English characters together, and someone else may be able to edit it) to make it easier for others. If you are having trouble entering Korean please have a look at some of our questions regarding Korean input on a computer.

Comment: https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/1664/how-is-hangul-composed-with-a-keyboard, https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/171/are-there-any-online-tools-available-for-entering-korean-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 sounds like "그림자 위치 보고." So maybe "그림자"(shadow) is a code name or something? This sounds very military. If the speaker is "그림자" himself it means "Shadow reporting location." If the sentence is addressed *to* "그림자" it would be imperative, "Shadow, report your location."

2 is surely [상판때기](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/4b5641c423394bb89687cd714327f1e8) 구멍나고 싶[네](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/a6fbf096c06d42bab60116c72e986db5)? "You want a hole in your face?"

It sounds like a North Korean dialect or, rather correctly, a South media imitating it.

3 may be "아니 얘가?" but I can't be sure of that. Too short, too small, too mumbling.